# Nginx and websockets on Heroku

Tags: nginx, heroku, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am searching for gateway/reverse proxy solution where we will have to route users to few API-s (more than 500 000 cals/daily API).

Conditions are that solution can work with:
- web sockets/https (+ load balance)
- is based on nginx 
- can be installed on Heroku

Does anybody have experience and what are the best **free** and **paid** tools for this?
Is there out of the box solutions?

- I have already install nginx buildpack on Heroku and try with OpenResty (lua-resty-websocket) but I want to hear other possibililties too.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to build the API as well? Are you talking about the load balancing layer? Heroku pretty much manages everything for you, you just need to set the dyno scaling parameters. I authored `iodine` and [`plezi`](http://www.plezi.io) for a Ruby solution as well as [facil.io](http://facil.io) for a C solution, but there are other popular choices out there that work great.

Comment: @Myst thank you for answer. We have already API (Swagger -> NodeJS) and we need gateway which can read JWT Auth (https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt)  tokens to route logged users to right place